# How can I make my own event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events

How can I make my own event in C#?

Comment: This question is timeless. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Here's an example of creating and using an event with C#

```
using System;

namespace Event_Example
{
    //First we have to define a delegate that acts as a signature for the
    //function that is ultimately called when the event is triggered.
    //You will notice that the second parameter is of MyEventArgs type.
    //This object will contain information about the triggered event.
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object source, MyEventArgs e);

    //This is a class which describes the event to the class that recieves it.
    //An EventArgs class must always derive from System.EventArgs.
    public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private string EventInfo;
        public MyEventArgs(string Text)
        {
            EventInfo = Text;
        }
        public string GetInfo()
        {
            return EventInfo;
        }
    }

    //This next class is the one which contains an event and triggers it
    //once an action is performed. For example, lets trigger this event
    //once a variable is incremented over a particular value. Notice the
    //event uses the MyEventHandler delegate to create a signature
    //for the called function.
    public class MyClass
    {
        public event MyEventHandler OnMaximum;
        private int i;
        private int Maximum = 10;
        public int MyValue
        {
            get
            {
                return i;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value <= Maximum)
                {
                    i = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //To make sure we only trigger the event if a handler is present
                    //we check the event to make sure it's not null.
                    if(OnMaximum != null)
                    {
                        OnMaximum(this, new MyEventArgs("You've entered " +
                            value.ToString() +
                            ", but the maximum is " +
                            Maximum.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        //This is the actual method that will be assigned to the event handler
        //within the above class. This is where we perform an action once the
        //event has been triggered.
        static void MaximumReached(object source, MyEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetInfo());
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Now lets test the event contained in the above class.
            MyClass MyObject = new MyClass();
            MyObject.OnMaximum += new MyEventHandler(MaximumReached);

            for(int x = 0; x <= 15; x++)
            {
                MyObject.MyValue = x;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After visiting a hundred explanations, this finally helped me understand. SE was right, posts *are* still relevant after several years.

Comment: {Meh!} I always **forget** to write in the `event` portion for the class.

Comment: Who's still learning in 2022?? I know I am. Pretty cool you can create a custom event.

Answer (score 56):

I have a full discussion of events and delegates in my [events article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx). For the simplest kind of event, you can just declare a public event and the compiler will create both an event and a field to keep track of subscribers:

```
public event EventHandler Foo;
```

If you need more complicated subscription/unsubscription logic, you can do that explicitly:

```
public event EventHandler Foo
{
    add
    {
        // Subscription logic here
    }
    remove
    {
        // Unsubscription logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to call the event from my code, but it turns out to be really obvious. You just call it like a method passing it a sender and EventArgs object. [ie. if (fooHappened) Foo(sender, eventArgs); ]

Comment: @Richard: Not quite; you need to handle the case where there are no subscribers, so the delegate reference will be null.

Comment: Looking forward to the C# 4 update on thread safe events in the article you linked.  Really great work, @JonSkeet!

Answer (score 25):

You can declare an event with the following code:

```
public event EventHandler MyOwnEvent;
```

A custom delegate type instead of EventHandler can be used if needed.

You can find detailed information/tutorials on the use of events in .NET in the article *[Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score 6):

to do it we have to know the three components

1. the place responsible for `firing the Event`
2. the place responsible for `responding to the Event`
3. the Event itself

   a. Event

   b .EventArgs

   c. EventArgs enumeration

now lets create Event that fired when a function is called

but I my order of solving this problem like this: I'm using the class before I create it

1. the place responsible for `responding to the Event`

   ```
   NetLog.OnMessageFired += delegate(object o, MessageEventArgs args) 
   {
           // when the Event Happened I want to Update the UI
           // this is WPF Window (WPF Project)  
           this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
           {
               LabelFileName.Content = args.ItemUri;
               LabelOperation.Content = args.Operation;
               LabelStatus.Content = args.Status;
           });
   };
   ```

NetLog is a static class I will Explain it later

the next step is

2. the place responsible for `firing the Event`

   ```
   //this is the sender object, MessageEventArgs Is a class I want to create it  and Operation and Status are Event enums
   NetLog.FireMessage(this, new MessageEventArgs("File1.txt", Operation.Download, Status.Started));
   downloadFile = service.DownloadFile(item.Uri);
   NetLog.FireMessage(this, new MessageEventArgs("File1.txt", Operation.Download, Status.Finished));
   ```

the third step

3. the Event itself

I warped The Event within a class called NetLog

```
public sealed class NetLog
{
    public delegate void MessageEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs args);

    public static event MessageEventHandler OnMessageFired;
    public static void FireMessage(Object obj,MessageEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (OnMessageFired != null)
        {
            OnMessageFired(obj, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}

public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string ItemUri { get; private set; }
    public Operation Operation { get; private set; }
    public Status Status { get; private set; }

    public MessageEventArgs(string itemUri, Operation operation, Status status)
    {
        ItemUri = itemUri;
        Operation = operation;
        Status = status;
    }
}

public enum Operation
{
    Upload,Download
}

public enum Status
{
    Started,Finished
}
```

this class now contain `the Event`, `EventArgs` and `EventArgs Enums` and `the function` responsible for firing the event

sorry for this long answer

Comment: They key difference in this answer is making the event static, which allows events to be received without requiring a reference to the object which fired the event. Great for subscribing to events from multiple independent controls.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you need to create an event, its handler and a delegate. Also you need to subscribe to the event and fire it.

A delegate defines the signature of the event handler method that will handle the event. That would be your code. For example:

```
public static void MyEventHandlerMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event handled");
}
```

You can use the following line to declare the event:

```
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

In order to activate the handler it is necessary to subscribe to the event:

```
MyEvent += MyEventHandlerMethod;
```

Now you just need to fire your event. You probably want to create another method for this:

```
public void FireMyEvent()
{
  if (MyEvent != null) // check if the event is not null (for ex. if the eventhandler was not subscribed)
  {
     MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

}
```