# C# Winforms .Net - Dynamic Communication Between Two Forms

Tags: winforms, communication

I've two froms which need to communicate simultaneously. When certain element in FORM B is clicked, FORM A is shown and some operation is performed. But the foreach loop inside FORM B should work when i click some next button in FORM A after the first operation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the constructor of your `FormA`

```
public FormA(Form F1)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   formB = frm as FormB;            
}
```

Show the form from **FormB** as

```
FormA frmA = new FormA(this);
frmA.Show();
```

Now you have a reference of `FormB` in **FormA**. Now expose the loop logic in a public method which could be accessed by this instance of `FormB`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create your own events in **FormB** and subscribe to them in **FormA**
here is a few examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea(v=vs.71).aspx
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers

Also here is a greate sample about how to do this:
[How can I make my own event in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623451/how-can-i-make-my-own-event-in-c)

Note also,while what V4Vendetta offered would be the easy way to do this-this however is probably the better way to do this,and also a better practice.